# Aws elastic search implementation with postgres database

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am to implement AWS elastic search on postgres database!

I am not getting any proper link how to get it implemented.

Please suggest some key inputs how i have to proceed on this.

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

This is a old question, still I am answering for future googlers.

Elastic search comes with it's own database and full text search capacity .It stores the data in inverted indices . And it's really fast and gives the results in near real time . If you have data in postgres then you need to move it to Elastic search .The process in pretty simple using Python/Java. All you need to keep in mind that elastic search data should be in-sync with postgres . This way , you can utilize the complete features of elastic search